# REST Web Service with jQgrid Examples in MVC3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, rest

I am a beginner in using jQgrid with REST Web service. Please give an example

How to use REST Web service with jQgrid.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post on [jqGrid, REST, AJAX and Spring MVC Integration](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/jqgrid-rest-ajax-spring-mvc-integration.html) should help you.